# Magento 2 add body class into as per current page using toolbar.php plugin for category and search results page

Tags: layout, blocks, magento2.2.2, toolbar

I have created plugin for `toolbar.php 
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar`

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Category Page'));
    $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('class'. $this->getCurrentPage() );     
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page-title')->setPageTitle('Custom Title');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

On product listing, need to add existing page number in body class.